# TYPO3: Get UID of created record

Tags: typo3

I need the UID of the record which just has been or is about to be created through the frontend.

```
public function createAction(\Vendor\EXT\Domain\Model\FeUserX $newFeUserX)
{
    // $this->addFlashMessage('The object was created.', '', \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\AbstractMessage::ERROR);

    $uid = $newFeUserX->getUid(); // something like this

    $this->feUserXRepository->add($newFeUserX);
    $this->redirect('list');
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Found it by myself ;)

```
public function createAction(\Vendor\EXT\Domain\Model\FeUserX $newFeUserX)
{
    // force to store data
    $this->feUserXRepository->add($newFeUserX);
    $persistenceManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\PersistenceManager');
    $persistenceManager->persistAll();

    $uid = $newFeUserX->getUid();

    // code which
    // uses $uid
    // goes here

    $this->redirect('new');
}
```

Comment: Of course you can also just inject persistence manager, the same way as any repository (don't forget proper annotation)